# Call to undefined function wp() in wp-blog-header.php

Tags: php, wp-admin, wp-blog-header.php

I am getting this error:

> `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp() in /home/pgcimykfka2h/public_html/apni-rasoi.com/wp-blog-header.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/pgcimykfka2h/public_html/apni-rasoi.com/index.php(24): require() #1 {main} thrown in /home/pgcimykfka2h/public_html/apni-rasoi.com/wp-blog-header.php on line 16`

Comment: have you made changes to WP core? Or tried to load `wp-blog-header.php` from a standalone PHP file you've created? Your question doesn't say what you're trying to do when the error happens, or the URL, recent changes, or if you did the standard debugging technique of disabling everything and turning it back on 1 by 1 until the problem returns to identify the culprit

Comment: @TomJNowell This problem has been happening frequently in WordPress 5+. I've had it happen on 3 sites in the last 6 months on different domains and hosts. 2 of the sites were fresh with no plugins.

Comment: For some reason wp-load.php got blanked. Uploaded a fresh one and it fixed it.